# Can we pass a char* to const string&?

Tags: c++

Is the following code acceptable in C++? If so, what happens? Does it create a temp string variable and pass its address?

```
void f(const string& s) {
}
const char kJunk[] = "junk";
f(kJunk);
```

Comment: It would take you less than a minute to try this out...

Comment: It's fine, it does create a temporary string object and pass a reference to it.

Comment: your avatar doesn't approve the use of C++, you are clearly doing it wrong.

Comment: Nice answers below.  Someone (or all of ya) should describe why this is ok but why it wouldn't be with a method taking a non-const `string&`

Comment: @Grimm The Opiner: I was just thinking about that and tried to use a method using a string&. That didn't compile as there is no string constructor using a non-const char*. I believe it's an issue with const correctness. So in short: You can't use a non-const string& as argument.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, it's acceptable. The compiler will call the `string(const char *)` constructor and create a temporary that will be bound to `s` for the duration of the call. When the fall to `f` returns the temporary will be destroyed.

Comment: Hm, do you also happen to have any links to official resources that can prove it?

Answer (score 3):

The argument that is the character array is implicitly converted to a temporary object of type std::string and the compiler passes const reference to this temporary object to the function. When the statement with the call of the function will finish its work the temporary object will be deleted.

Answer (score 2):

> Does it create a temp string variable and pass its address?

Yes, it's equivalent to:

```
void f(const std::string& s) {
}
const char kJunk[] = "junk";
f(std::string(kJunk));
```